# What kind of insect is this?

Tags: zoology, entomology, species-identification

Found in Russia in the kitchen. It is about 3 mm long.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related[Tiny dark-colored bug ID in Amman-Jordan](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/82449/16866)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a flour beetle, the two most common and likely types are the confused flour beetle and red flour beetle but to identify look at the antennae. I'd suggest it is [the confused flour beetle](http://ento.psu.edu/extension/factsheets/flour-beetle) because the antenna go from thin to fat quite gradually, though the pictures may not be good enough for that to be certain.

Other commonly used names are tribolium (the genus name) or flour weevil. They are also used in labs as a model organism, groups in my last two labs have used them. [They are a pest](http://www.orkin.com/other/beetles/flour-beetles/) and you should probably get rid of them.

> "Both types of beetles are often found not only in infested grains,
>   but in crevices in pantries and cabinet, as well. Damage to food is
>   caused somewhat by the beetles' feeding, but also by their dead
>   bodies, fecal pellets, and foul-smelling secretions. In addition to
>   creating a foul odor, the beetles' presence encourages the growth of
>   mold." - [Wiki](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confused_flour_beetle).

Comment: Can we agree that "confused flour beetle" is a fantastic name?

Comment: @Oreotrephes definitely, never heard of that name before, but are now curious how it came about.

Comment: @damien it's because people often confuse the two when identifying them.