# Can anyone identify this bug, it's got six legs

Tags: species-identification

Hi I live in the midwest (Wisconsin), these have recently started appearing all over my basement. Anyone know what they might be? They are about 2.5 mm long and they are quite active. I don't keep any food items in the basement they they would be able to fed on.  [image]

Comment: Please indicate size, describe behavior, and comment about any stored food in your basement or in nearby places of your home.

Comment: Related[Tiny dark-colored bug ID in Amman-Jordan](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/82449/16866)

Comment: I'd look hard through your possible food storage areas; they may not be infesting the sorts of foods you'd expect, I've definitely seen some relatives here in WI. See for examples https://extension.umn.edu/product-and-houseplant-pests/pantry-pests-insects-found-stored-food#beetles-55711 https://hortnews.extension.iastate.edu/red-flour-beetle https://hort.extension.wisc.edu/articles/sawtoothed-grain-beetle/ I'm not certain which exactly you have, I'm guessing @theforestecologist can either provide a more definitive answer here or mark as a duplicate of the related ID.